# Geo Nodes: How to use curve parameters to control specific instances

Tags: geometry-nodes

I’m trying to use a spiral curve as an instance and I want each instance to have a random end heights and revolutions but having trouble figure out how to use those parameters from the spiral curve after creating instances. Trim curve sort of works but I can’t control the spiral beyond that.

Comment: simple answer: you cannot work with spiral as instances here. You have to create these curve spirals yourself by math nodes. There are a lot of questions here and answers, why you cannot change instances after instancing (because they are just copies and you can only change scale/rotation and position).

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer" so that this question will not continue to be displayed as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite clear what the result should be, but the height (number of turns) as well as the *Trim Factor* you could make variable in the following way:

[image]

Of course, the flexibility is limited, because after an instantiation only the individual parameters of the curve are changeable, but not those of the spiral.